# How can I hide notifications my site is displaying if it is focused and brought to the foreground?

Tags: web-push, progressive-web-apps

Context: I am building a progressive web apps that sends my users push notifications with service worker.

Is there a way to ensure that if the user browses to my site while notifications are currently showing that the notifications are hidden?

I want to avoid the situation where they navigated to my site and the notifications are still displaying, now stale.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, from the document you can clear all currently showing notifications like this:

```
// From a document.
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
    registration.getNotifications().then(notifications =>
        notifications.forEach(notification => notification.close()));
});
```

You could choose to simply run this code every time a page loads to solve your case, or you could additionally add a `focus` event listener to the document that runs this code to ensure it is applied every time your site is brought into focus.